# The "F-word" in N-gram Viewer

Tags: etymology, literature, frequency-analysis

I was simply fiddling with [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuck&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuck%3B%2Cc0) when my apparently naughty mind made me type the (real) "F-word" onto the text field, (the time was also chosen randomly, (1750-to-1993)), the [results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuck&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuck%3B%2Cc0) baffled me. (more like upside down flattened bell-curve)

[image]

From the results it seems entire 19th century and early-to-mid 20th writers heavily eschewed the word *fuck* (maybe the writers of that period were polite?) Is it an interesting coincidence or is Google playing with us?

How can it be that such a heavily used colloquial word, suddenly vanished from writings, only to rearise in modern times?

<sub>NOTE: This is purely an inquisitive question, I have no intention to make judgement on writers of any era.</sub>

Comment: This is weird, there's a fairly extensive list of books, some without the names of authors, all [containing the word *fuck* in their titles](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22fuck%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1784,cd_max:1989&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=Y7RAV6-vCIjPgAb6-qnADA#q=%22fuck%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1784,cd_max:1989,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=0). I did some minimal research and came up empty handed. I wonder if some of these titles actually exist. NSFW

Comment: One of @Mari-LouA's examples (from 1805, but in the text, not a title) is a [misreading of *suck* using a long s](https://books.google.it/books?id=TR9AAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA984&dq=%22fuck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYkbPK8-vMAhVBLsAKHZNsDw84FBDoAQg2MAU#v=onepage&q=%22fuck%22&f=false). I wonder if those instances the N-gram has before 1820 are similar misreadings and the graph should be entirely flat before 1960.

Comment: The shape of the curve makes the possible confusion with "suck" interesting, if that's the cause. The practically identical percentage values seem... odd.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I went back to the 1800s in your list and found one case where it appeared that "fuck" was being proposed as a neologism for a class of criminals, in court documents.

Comment: @HotLicks oh, that's very very curious.  What class of criminal would that be?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It was unclear, embedded in some legalese, but it did not appear to be referring to sex offenses.  IIRC, the words went something like "*fuck* should be used to refer to criminals and malefactors".  (Italics theirs.)  (Sorry I didn't hang onto a reference, but I had places to go.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The problem of search engines, etc. It's very clear why the text should be searchable. And it's not clear because some people got confused, IMO.

Comment: @Mary and HotLicks - Sounds like [skell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skell).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Did you check any of your Ngram results?  The early hits are mostly false drops from typographical and OCR considerations, so the tail on the distribution continues to the left.  Prudishness and censorship combined to make it ʃucking impossible to get the word published until "modern" times.  Now no one cares about the word when the internet is dedicated to videos of the act.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems more like a Technical artifact, here's one more,I never imagined that [Shakespeare will ever use the f-word](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pvMjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA412&dq=%22fuck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJuIasgOzMAhVG4qYKHabiDTQ4HhDoAQhGMAg#v=onepage&q=%22fuck%22&f=false)

Comment: @AnkurPatel Actually, the highlighted word in your link is *suck*, but spelled with the defunct [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s). The letter *f* has a crossbar that extends on either side; the long s, when it has a crossbar at all, has it only on the left side.

Comment: @AnkurPatel - Yep, compare to "fpiders" two words earlier.  I'm guessing that's really "spiders".

Comment: `the internet is dedicated to videos of the act` You misspelled **cat**.

Comment: If there are community members who take issue with a moderator's enforcement of site policy, the proper course of action is to post a discussion question on Meta. The moderators have discussed MariLou's edit and agreed that *ʃucking* is a good compromise, as it is a humorous example of the OCR transcription error.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox So the moderators discussed MariLou's edit, did they?  I suppose it would be churlish of me to point out that it's not a compromise at all.  And while you all were at it, did you discuss one of your number threatening to flag a poster who hadn't violated site policy?  Because, trust me, that would have been the the topic of the Meta discussion, not the bowdlerization.  And I see the comment fairies have done their magic to tidy up that bit of history.

Answer (score 26):

It looks like what Andrew Leach and deadrat pointed out are very keen observations. I checked about 50 links of books before 1820 times, but nowhere have I found the word "fuck" (almost everywhere it is a misreference of **[Long S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)** (f without the crossbar) , as in ſuck (suck), ſucked (sucked), ſuck'd (suck'd), ſucking(sucking) and other variations). This explains why [the anomalous graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuck&year_start=1700&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuck%3B%2Cc0) went above sea level before 1820.

[image]
<sup>Screen shot from *The Dramatic Works of Shakspeare: In Six Volumes, Volume 3*, Clarendon Press, 1789.</sup>

It seems like "fuck" is a pretty modern word not much used by the writers of 18th and early 19th century (even though Wikipedia says its first accepted usage was registered on the 15th century). This modernness can be demonstrated with N-gram if I replace "fuck" with "Fuck" and we can see the bold green bar erasing the apparent aberration.

[image]

> NOTE :  Declaring "fuck" as a pretty modern word is purely based on
>   pieces of evidence provided by the N-gram graphs whose corpus includes
>   only the uploaded published text to google books. So chances are there
>   that this can be a tentative declaration. But still we can get
>   partially the idea of its very modernness in prints.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuck&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfuck%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfuck%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFuck%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "not used by" <> "not known to".

Comment: In addition, did find one case where the name "Puck" was mis-read as "Fuck".

Comment: The claim that “‘fuck’ is a pretty modern word not much used by the writers of 18th and early 19th century” is not supported by the evidence in this answer. It may not have been *published* until recently, but there are ways to use a word aside from in published text, including personal correspondence and, ya know, speaking. The former is a rather smaller portion of the ngram corpus I would imagine, and the latter quite obviously isn’t present at all.

Comment: @KRyan -- So where is the *evidence* of this?

Comment: @HotLicks I am not making any claim, I am saying that the available evidence does not support the claim made in this answer. The evidence here only covers written and published text available in the ngram corpus. Thus, it can only be used to make statements *about that kind of text*, but the claim here is much, much broader than that.

Comment: @KRyan - Yet generally we date a word by the earliest known use.  The earliest definitive use I can find is 1954, with a somewhat questionable one in 1935.  Various online etymologies give dates back several centuries, but they typically are radically different spellings or even codes of one sort or another.  (And I've seen no evidence in this thread that the word was used by writers in the 18th and 19th century.)

Comment: Would have upvoted but for the "modern word" claim. OED gives 1528 marginal note "fuckin Abbot" as earliest definitive example in English. The encoded version from around 1500 is in medieval Latin, but it seems that "fvccant" appears as loan word from English. If we take "fuck" in the same tradition as "hit", "tap", "bang", etc., in which words with a sense of "strike" gain the sense "copulate", then "fuck" probably took something close to its current form during the High German consonant shift.

Comment: You formatted *It seems like "fuck" …* as __code__, please format it as a __quote__ by using `> ` at the start of the line.

Comment: Please remove your offensive edit. I offered my correction in good faith, and would have upvoted once the statement in question was removed. Retain your false and misleading *statement* if you must.

Comment: @DeveloperInDevelopment bro/sis, I mean no offense to you nor to anyone,I respect the good faith, I am sorry if you felt that way, kindly see the edit :)

Comment: "...still we can get partially the idea of its very modernness" **in print**, I think you mean.